# xslt select hard coded string with node value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to add in front of every select value this hard coded string **mobile/**

this select hyperlink from xml:

```
<a href="{Hyperlink/a/@href}" name="xslt">
```

I tried this but it only gets value from xslt expression:

```
<a href="'mobile/' + {Hyperlink/a/@href}"> XXX </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `concat()`

```
<a href="{concat('mobile/',Hyperlink/a/@href)}" name="xslt"> XXX </a>
```

Also, `<a href="mobile/{Hyperlink/a/@href}"> XXX </a>` should've worked for you originally. Are you sure that your current context would have `Hyperlink` as a child?